# Openlayers filter strategy on wfs deactivate problem

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, wfs-t

I have a filter control which works nicely. However, when I try to reset/remove the filter, I don't get the original features back. The debugger shows my features array as still only being the reduced number of features, yet shows the filter strategy as being inactive.

I set up the strategy on layer instantiation like this:

```
this.strategies = { 
    bbox: new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),
    filter: new OpenLayers.Strategy.Filter(),
};

// initialisation stuff here ...

layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    this.layerName, {
        projection: this.projection,
        strategies: [            
            this.strategies.bbox,
            this.strategies.filter,
        ],
        protocol: protocol,
        styleMap: styleMap,
    }
);
```

I set the filter like this:

```
filter: function () {

    var olLayer = this.olLayer;
    var attribute = document.getElementById
        ( "layer-search-attribute" ).value;
    var value = document.getElementById( "layer-search-value" ).value;
    var type = OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE;
    var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: type,
        property: attribute,
        value: value,
    });

    this.strategies.filter.activate(); 
    this.strategies.filter.setFilter( filter );
    olLayer.redraw();

    // back to the map page
    $.mobile.changePage( "#mappage" );
}, // end filter ()
```

And I remove it like this:

```
resetFilter: function () {
    console.log("Removing filter on:", this.layerName );
    var olLayer = this.olLayer;

    this.strategies.filter.deactivate();  
    olLayer.redraw();       

    // back to the map page
    $.mobile.changePage( "#mappage" );
}, // end resetFilter ()
```

I've also tried `olLayer.refresh({ force: true })` without success.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.strategies.filter.setFilter();
```

should work

I use a WFS-Layer for filtering:

```
var filterStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Filter();

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        strategies: [filterStrategy]
    });
```

To reset the filter I just use

```
filterStrategy.setFilter();
```

and this works well.
You could of course also set a filter that will give you back all your features and pass this filter to filterStrategy.setFilter().

For further information see http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Filter-js.html